# Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'CGFloat'

Tags: swift, swift2

This code has no syntax error.

```
for (var m = 1.0; m < 3.0; m += 0.1) {
}
```

On the other hand, the below code has an syntax error.
Error Message: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'CGFloat'

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")
for (var n = 1.0; n < image!.size.height; n += 0.1) {
}
```

Why it happend? I tried to use `if let` instead of force unwrap, but I had the same error.

Environment:
Xcode7.0.1
Swift2

Comment: Did you check the types of the operands of `<`? What type has `n`? What type has `image!.size.height`? Are those equal or not? What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My confirmation was lacking. I'll check type on the next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `image!.size.height` return `CGFloat` any type of your `n` is `Double` so you need to convert your `CGFloat` to `Double` this way `Double(image!.size.height)`.

And your code will be:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "myImage")

for (var n = 1.0; n < Double(image!.size.height); n += 0.1) {

}
```

Or you can assign type to `n` as `CGFloat` this way:

```
for (var n : CGFloat = 1.0; n < image!.size.height; n += 0.1) {

}
```

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that '1.0' was built as CGFloat.
And I misunderstood too that the error message said.

Thank you very much for your answer.
My confirmation was lacking.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly classier way to do this is with the `stride()` family of functions.

```
// Create the image, crashing if it doesn't exist. since the error case has been handled, there is no need to force unwrap the image anymore.
guard let image = UIImage(named: "myImage") else { fatalError() }

// The height parameter returns a CGFloat, convert it to a Double for consistency across platforms.
let imageHeight = Double(image.size.height)

// Double conforms to the `Strideable` protocol, so we can use the stride(to:by:) function to enumerate through a range with a defined step value.
for n in 1.0.stride(to: imageHeight, by: 0.1) {
    print("\(n)")
    // ... Or do whatever you want to in here.
}
```

Comment: Wow! It is excellent way!!
I didn't know Strideable protocol but major type, like Double, Float, Int, conform this. It's very obvious and I'm exciting!!
Thank you for your advice! I use this!

Answer (score 1):

Please check this one on Swift 4.0

```
var enteringAmountDouble: Double? {
    return Double(amountTextField.text!)
}
var userMoneyDouble: Double? = userWalletMerchants?.balance
if (enteringAmountDouble?.isLessThanOrEqualTo(userMoneyDouble!))! {
    print("Balance is there .. U can transfer money to someone!")
}else{
    APIInterface.instance().showAlert(title: "Please check you are balance", message: "Insufficient balance")
    return
}
```